# Download URL for a Dropbox file OAuth 2.0

Tags: c#, file, oauth-2.0, dropbox, access-token

I am using the [DropboxRESTAPi](https://github.com/saguiitay/DropboxRestAPI) to upload files to dropbox and it works just fine. I need to further generate a download URL for the customers which I currently use this url format below:

https://content.dropboxapi.com/1/files/auto/THEPATH?access_token=ACCESSTOKEN&oauth_version=2.0&oauth_consumer_key=THEKEY";

My question is: Is it secure to provide this url to the customer where the access token and other infos are available?

Is there a better way to generate download URL using OAuth 2.0?

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not safe to provide your access token to others. Any malicious user could then use the access token with the Dropbox API directly to access your Dropbox account directly, e.g., to download other files, delete files, etc.

A better solution would be to generate shared links, and distribute only those shared links as necessary:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-create_shared_link_with_settings